# Python. Regular expression not returning output

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to `findall` instances of the string `"PB"` and the digits that follow it, but when I call.

```
number_all = re.findall(r'\bPB\b([0-9])\d+', ' '.join(number_list))
```

the  `([0-9])\d+` doesn't return an output. I check my output file, `sequence.txt` but there is nothing inside it. If i just do `\bPB\b` it outputs `"PB"` but no numbers.

My input file, `raw-sequence.txt` looks like this:

```
WB (19, 21, 24, 46, 60)
WB (12, 11, 9, 23, 49)
PB (18, 21, 10, 5, 5)
WB (2, 14, 2, 29, 67)
WB (1, 8, 1, 16, 52)
PB (2, 11, 8, 3, 4)
```

How can I output the following lines to sequence.txt?

```
PB (18, 21, 10, 5, 5)
PB (2, 11, 8, 3, 4)
```

Here is my current code:

```
sequence_raw_buffer = open('c:\\sequence.txt', 'a')
with open('c:\\raw-sequence.txt') as f:
  number_list = f.read().splitlines()
  number_all = re.findall(r'\bPB\b([0-9])\d+', ' '.join(number_list))
  unique = list(set(number_all))
  for i in unique:
    sequence_raw_buffer.write(i + '\n')
  print "done"
  f.close()
  sequence_raw_buffer.close()
```

Comment: regex101.com is great for testing regular expressions

Comment: You should really read the [`re` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: You just want lines starting with "PB"?

Comment: Because you really don't need regex for that.

Comment: yes Mad pretty at the moment all i want is PB lines called and output in sequence.txt

Comment: Not sure why you got the downvote. You're clearly a beginner, but this is a good question with all the required elements and a good amount of effort put into it.

Comment: Thank you Mad Physicist! yes, im a beginner but your solution works great. i was also able to split the WB's into its own sequence and now next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the code you show, regex are an unnecessary over-complication to your problem. You can just iterate over the lines from the input file and dump the ones for which `line.startswith("PB")` returns `True`.

```
with open(r'c:\raw-sequence.txt', 'r') as f, open(r'c:\sequence.txt', 'a') as sequence_raw_buffer:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("PB"):
            print(line, file=sequence_raw_buffer)
```

This illustrates the fact that files can be iterated over line-by-line. I use print to dump the line because it will append the correct line terminator that the `for` loop strips off.

This example also shows you how to put multiple context managers into a single `with` block. You should have all your file in a `with` block, whether input or output, because I/O errors are a possibility in both directions.

Now, if you are trying to use regex for practice or because the match is really more complicated than what you present here, you can try

```
PB\s*\((?:\d+,\s*)*\d+\)
```

This matches as follows:

- Literal `PB`
- Optional unlimited number of spaces `\s*`
- Literal open parens `\(`
- Optional non-capturing group `(?:)*`, repeated as many times as necessary, containing

  - At least one digit `\d+`
  - Literal comma `,`
  - Any number of spaces `\s*`
- At least one actual number `\d`
- Literal close parens `\)`

I would not bother concatenating the whole file together and using `findall` on that though, unless your expression can span multiple lines. I would prefer to still use the approach shown above, because in all but a few cases that I can think of, textual data will generally be delimited by newlines:

```
pattern = re.compile('PB\s*\((?:\d+,\s*)*\d+\)')
...
            if pattern.match(line):
...
```

Pre-compiling the pattern once makes the program run faster, but you could call [`re.match(..., line)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) every time as well.

Comment: Ah, I coded this up myself almost exactly the same in the time you wrote this. Beaten to the punch :)

I just want to note that the output is dumb about newlines if you're running the it multiple times (eg. with different files) regardless of if you're using print (too many newlines) or write (not enough).

You can get around it by using `print(line, file=outputFile, end='')` inside the for loop and `print('', file=outputFile)` outside, or `outputFile.write(line)` inside and `outputFile.write("\n")` outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex: PB\s?\(([0-9]*,?\s?)*\)

Comment: This appears to return `['', '']` when run on the OP's input file.

Comment: I tried it here, it seems to work, https://regex101.com/r/GtqFJg/1 .
Can you send me the text you are using?

Comment: Sure. Even better, here is the string in an interactive environment that shows the output too: https://repl.it/IOFL

Comment: Ok, the problem was with the groups i was creating, this should work `PB \(.*?\)`

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that you are missing

1. You are missing a space between word boundary(`\b`) and bracket `(`
2. Parenthesis `()` have different meanings in regex context. Parenthesis denotes capturing group. To match parenthesis literally you need to escape it.

Now to match the exact pattern you intend, you can use [*`this`*](https://regex101.com/r/xsXypF/1)

```
\bPB\s+\((?:\s*\d+\s*,\s*)*\d+\)
```

If you want to only match lines with `PB` you can directly search for `PB`